# How to pass a buffer argument to a control method in `acpiexec` prompt?

Tags: acpi, acpica

I defined a buffer object and a control method to iterate the buffer object.

```asl
DefinitionBlock ("dsdt.asl", "DSDT", 0x02, "", "", 0x0) 
{ 
    Name (BUF0, Buffer() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})

    Method (IDXA, 1) 
    {
        local0 = sizeof(Arg0) 
        local1 = 0 // use this as the index value 
        printf ("The size of the buffer is %o, Arg0 is: %o", local0, Arg0) 
        while (local0 > local1) 
        {
            printf ("inside loop:")
            printf ("%o", DeRefOf(Arg0[local1]))
            local1++ 
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles it with `iasl`:

> iasl dsdt.asl

Then I run it with `acpiexec`:

> acpiexec dsdt.aml

In the `acpiexec` prompt, I tried to call the `IDXA` method with `\BUF0` as arg0:

```
- eval \IDXA \BUF0  
Evaluating \IDXA
ACPI Debug:  "The size of the buffer is 0000000000000008, Arg0 is: 0000000000000000"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 0x555d39f95770 (20190509/exresop-617)
ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20190509/dswexec-500)
Failed at AML Offset 00056, Opcode 0088: Index (Arg0, Local1)

Initialized Local Variables for Method [IDXA]:
    Local0: 0x555d39f95840 <Obj>             Integer 0000000000000008
    Local1: 0x555d39f956f0 <Obj>             Integer 0000000000000000

Initialized Arguments for Method [IDXA]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
    Arg0:   0x555d39f95770 <Obj>             Integer 0000000000000000

ACPI Error: Aborting method \IDXA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20190509/psparse-581)
ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, while executing \IDXA from AML Debugger (20190509/dbexec-226)
Evaluation of \IDXA failed with status AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE
```

The error message says "Arg0 is: 0000000000000000".

And it seems it is an integer got passed in instead of a buffer array. So the index operator failed.

I can access the `\BUF0` on the `acpiexec` prompt. But I cannot pass it to the `\IDXA` method.

```
- eval \BUF0
Evaluating \BUF0
Evaluation of \BUF0 returned object 0x55b97b465cd0, external buffer length 28
  [Buffer] Length 0A =     0000: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 00 00 08                    // ..........
```

**How to pass `BUF0` to a ACPI control method in `acpiexec` prompt?**

Comment: @0andriy Could you turn your comment into an answer so I can mark it and release the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acpiexec` has a set of limited capabilities on what it can supply as arguments to the executed methods. Its help in particularly says:

```auto
Control Method Execution:            
  All <NameSeg>                       Evaluate all objects named NameSeg
  Evaluate <Namepath> [Arguments]     Evaluate object or control method
  Execute <Namepath> [Arguments]      Synonym for Evaluate
  Background <Namepath> [Arguments]   Evaluate object/method in a separate thread
  Thread <Threads><Loops><NamePath>   Spawn threads to execute method(s)
  Debug <Namepath> [Arguments]        Single-Step a control method
  [Arguments] formats:                Control method argument formats
     Hex Integer                      Integer
     "Ascii String"                   String
     (Hex Byte List)                  Buffer
         (01 42 7A BF)                Buffer example (4 bytes)
     [Package Element List]           Package
         [0x01 0x1234 "string"]       Package example (3 elements)
```

that arguments formats supported are: Integer, String, Buffer, and Package. At the end of this part of help the examples are being provided. So, the Buffer may be supplied only in the form of `( XX YY ZZ )`. There is nothing telling about references to the existing objects in ACPI namespace.

The workaround is to do it in a two steps:

- `eval BUF0` and copy the hex dump of the buffer (might require a bit more work if buffer is long enough);
- type `eval IDXA ( ...copy_and_paste_the_buffer_contents_here... )`

These steps will give you the desired result:

```auto
- eval BUF0
Evaluating \BUF0
Evaluation of \BUF0 returned object 0x583cfa5a2d60, external buffer length 28
  [Buffer] Length 0A =     0000: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A                    // ..........

- eval IDXA ( 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A )
Evaluating \IDXA
ACPI Debug:  "The size of the buffer is 000000000000000A, Arg0 is: 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0A"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "0000000000000001"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "0000000000000002"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "0000000000000003"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "0000000000000004"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "0000000000000005"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "0000000000000006"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "0000000000000007"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "0000000000000008"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "0000000000000009"
ACPI Debug:  "inside loop:"
ACPI Debug:  "000000000000000A"
No object was returned from evaluation of \IDXA
-
```

The proper solution is to patch `acpiexec` in order to add the required functionality. Since ACPICA is an Open Source project hosted on GitHub you can fork it, develop the feature, and send a PR back to the maintainers. Everybody will benefit from this.